# Application differs from activity to broadcastreceiver

Tags: android

I have my own singleton class which inherits from Application. In all my activities I get this shared class by using `DataClass dc = (DataClass) context.getApplicationContext();`.

this seems to work but when I trie to acces the singleton in a custom BroadCastReceiver I have an other instance of the Application.

Is that possible? Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

If i am not mistaken, a BroadcastReceiver runs on a different process then your activity. That means you'll have a different instance of Application on your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Then how should I pass variables to a broadCastReceiver? I could use intent.putExtra but since I need to pass a long variable this will be a lot of overhead

Comment: putExtra() is the easiest way. Also keep in mind that your the BroadcastReceiver call should not take much longer then a few seconds to execute, else it may be killed. Actually you cannot even bind to a service from within the receiver. I'd just use Intent as i dont have a better idea for now :P